# Apache POI - Conditional formatting - need to set different cell range for rule and formatting

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create an empty excel template using apache poi java. I need to add a rule - when column no. 3 is populated then columns from 7 to 12 need to be highlighted in some color (as a mandatory indicator for the user).

I could find below code which colors the cell when the condition is met on the same cell. But I want to color/format different cells when the condition is met on current cell.

```
`   XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
    ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(ComparisonOperator.GT, "5");

    PatternFormatting patternFmt = rule1.createPatternFormatting();
    patternFmt.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.index);

    sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(addressList.getCellRangeAddresses(), rule1); //when rule1 is met, same cell is colored yellow
```

But I want is when rule1 is met, then color a different cell range.

Is this possible in poi and how ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Excel` provides conditional formatting rules based on formulas.

The formula `=AND(ISNUMBER($C1), $C1>5)` returns `True` if the value in  `$C1` is numeric and greater than 5. If this formula is applied to the range `G1:L1000`, then each cell in this range will be true if the value in column `C` of the corresponding row fulfills that contition. That is because column `C` is fixated using `$C` in the formula. But the row numbers are not fixated and so are relative.

Example using `apache poi`:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class ConditionalFormatting {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("new sheet");
  SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

  ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("AND(ISNUMBER($C1), $C1>5)");
  PatternFormatting fill = rule.createPatternFormatting();
  fill.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.index);
  fill.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

  ConditionalFormattingRule[] cfRules = new ConditionalFormattingRule[]{rule};

  CellRangeAddress[] regions = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("G1:L1000")};

  sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, cfRules);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ConditionalFormatting.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Now if you put something in column `C` what is numeric and greater than 5, the cells in columns `G:L` will be filled yellow.

Comment: Thanks Axel, I was looking for something similar. Only thing, in your example, I need something like if C1 is not blank then columns G1 through L1 should be colored only if each of it is not blank. That is, when C1 is not blank and G1 is blank then G1 should be colored. But if C1 is not blank and G1 also is not blank, then G1 should not be colored and so on. Not sure if I have to create formula for each combination - C1 - G1, C1 - H1, etc

Comment: `sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("AND(ISNUMBER($C1), $C1>5, G1=\"\")")`:= true if in column `C` is a number AND value in `C` is greater than 5 AND respective column in applied range (`G` ... `L`) is empty.

Comment: Thanks again, this helped.  When value is filled in these colored cells, I want to remove the color of the respective cell. I understand I will have to write a formula for each of these cells (from G1 through H1) sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(ComparisonOperator.NOT_EQUAL, "\"\"")

 patternFmt.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.NO_FILL);