# Apache POI formula to check any of the cell from the range is not blank

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working with Apache POI, using conditional formating. I want to be able to write a formula such as - if any of the columns from within the specified range is not a number then highlight all of them. I am trying to use with the formula - ISNUMBER($J1:P1000). But this does not work.

```
ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("ISNUMBER($J1:P1000))");
```

If I try with just single cell with formula - ISNUMBER($J1) it works. But I want condition if any of the cells through J to P is a number then do some highlighting.

Details of code to highlight some cells based on some rule is given in this thread, so not repeating- [Apache POI - Conditional formatting - need to set different cell range for rule and formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50175877/apache-poi-conditional-formatting-need-to-set-different-cell-range-for-rule)

Comment: You seems not have understand how CF works. `ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("NOT(ISNUMBER(J1))");` applied to `CellRangeAddress.valueOf("J1:P1000")` matches for all cells in that `CellRangeAddress` which are fulfilling the rule. Tht is because there is not a `$` somewhere in the rule and so column letters as well as row numbers are relative and not fixated.

Comment: I understand when ISNUMBER(J1) is applied to CellRangeAddress.valueOf("J1:P1000"), it matches any cell in this range and color ONLY the matching cell. But I want when any cell in this range matches, color ALL the cells from J through P.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible using CF. Are you able creating that CF in `Excel`'s GUI? If not then `apache poi` also cannot do this.

Comment: From point of view the single cell `ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("(COUNT($J$1:$P$1000)>0)");` applied to `CellRangeAddress.valueOf("J1:P1000")` could work as you wants. `COUNT` does only count numbers. So if any cell in `J1:P1000` contains a number, count will be greater than 0. Please try.

Comment: Thanks Axel, this is exactly what I want. But I did not exactly understand $J$1:$P$1000. 
As per my understanding, $J is specific entry in J column, and just J (without $) is relative and applicable to all cells in CellRangeAddress.
What does $J$1 mean ?

Comment: Any good documentation for this would also help. 
You can copy the above solution into answer, and I can accept it as right answer.

Comment: There is not really a good description about formulas used as conditional formatting rules that I am knowing about. But see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question now (also took comments into account), the requirement is to highlight the whole range `J1:P[n]` (I will take `J1:P1000` for example) if any of the cells within this range contains numeric content. This is posible using a formula as the `ConditionalFormattingRule`.

**Background knowledge:**

Conditional formatting (CF) works having rules applied to a range of cells and having formats to use if the rule is fulfilled. While CF process runs, each cell in the applied range is tested whether it fulfills the rule. If so, the format will be used, if not, then not.

So if the rule is a formula, then we must look at this formula from point of view of each single cell in the range. There it plays a important role
whether cell references in the formula are relative or are fixated using `$`.

In cell references the `$` can fixing the column reference as well as the row reference. For example in `A1` both, the column reference as well as the row reference, are relative. In `$A1`, the column reference to column `A` is fix and the row reference is relative. In `A$1`, the column reference is relative and the row reference to row `1` is fix. In `$A$1` both, the column reference to column `A` as well as the row reference to row `1` are fix. So this last reference will always referencing cell `A1`.

**The concrete examples:**

In my answer [Apache POI - Conditional formatting - need to set different cell range for rule and formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50175877/apache-poi-conditional-formatting-need-to-set-different-cell-range-for-rule), which is related to this answer, a formula rule: `AND(ISNUMBER($C1), $C1>5)` is applied to the range `G1:L1000`. So from point of view the single cell in `G1:L1000`, the rule checks the following:

Is the cell value in column `$C` (always in column `C` because this reference is fixated), in same row where the single cell exists (because the row references are relative), numeric and greater than 5?

In comment I have suggested a rule `AND(ISNUMBER($C1), $C1>5, G1="")` applied to the same range `G1:L1000`. This checks the same as the above and:

Is the single cell in columns `G:L`, where the single cell exists, (not always in column `G` because the column reference is relative), in same row where the single cell exists (because the row references are relative), empty (equals an empty string)?

**Now your actual requirement:**

"to highlight the whole range `J1:P1000` if any of the cells within this range contans numeric content"

The function `COUNT` does only count numbers. So `COUNT($J$1:$P$1000)` will be greater than 0 if any cell in `J1:P1000` contains a number.

So

```
ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("(COUNT($J$1:$P$1000)>0)");
```

applied to `CellRangeAddress.valueOf("J1:P1000")` could work as you wants.

From point of view the single cell for each cell the `COUNT` must count the whole range. Thats why the references in `$J$1:$P$1000` are all fixated and are not relative.

Comment: That's a very useful explanation. Thank you !