# How to set priority for conditional formatting rules using apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a use case where I need to apply two different conditional formatting rules. In rule1, I will be painting an entire row with a certain color. In rule2, if the text contains certain keywords or if it meets certain requirements, I need to repaint this particular cell with a different color (error highlighting). On building the workbook, always rule1 is taking precedence but I want rule2 as priority no 1.

```
 ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("COUNTIF($F$2:$F$11,F2)>1");
 FontFormatting font = rule1.createFontFormatting();
 font.setFontStyle(false, true);
 font.setFontColorIndex(IndexedColors.BLUE.index);

 CellRangeAddress[] regions = {
            CellRangeAddress.valueOf("F2:F11")
 };

 sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule1);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50175877/apache-poi-conditional-formatting-need-to-set-different-cell-range-for-rule

Comment: What happens if you create them the other way round, with the error one first?

Comment: @Gagravarr It works but the rule1 needs to go first because of the design and few other constraints.

Comment: Your code only sets one rule. So how is this code related to the question? Please provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).